# API to perform queries on stocks and financial derivatives

Tags: programming, data, database

Is there a native and free API and DB to request information such as:

- All the companies which their `P/E` ratio is greater than 50
- The closing prices of stock `$XYZ`

Comment: Mathematica has lots of this built into their FinancialData[] function.

Comment: @Jagra, How do you get the data into the Array, my question is how to collect the data rather than how to process it. thanks

Comment: @0x90 - That is exactly what FinancialData[] does. Please refer to [its documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FinancialData.html).

Comment: @acheong87 add this as an answer. is there anything similar for matlab?

Comment: Like I said last time I closed your question, this is a site for *people who work in quantitative finance*.

Comment: @chrisaycock if you find it more suitable for SO ? pls migrate it to there.

Answer (score 1):

Try the yahoo screener:
http://screener.finance.yahoo.com/newscreener.html

The java version will run on windows/osx/linux and you can download to a csv.

Edit:
the java version no longer works.

This link is the best yahoo has.
https://screener.finance.yahoo.com/stocks.html

Quandl has all of this data as well so people can generate their own data.